# Paley-Wiener stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

This is from the book on Brownian Motion by Morters and Peres.
let $(B_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $F\in C[0,1]$ differentiable. Then define

$$\xi_n=2^n\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}\left[F\left(\frac{j}{2^n}\right)-F\left(\frac{j-1}{2^n}\right)\right]\left[B\left(\frac{j}{2^n}\right)-B\left(\frac{j-1}{2^n}\right)\right]$$

and it is claimed that

$$\xi_n-\xi_{n-1}=2^n\sigma_n\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n-1}}\left[2F\left(\frac{2j-1}{2^n}\right)-F\left(\frac{2j-2}{2^n}\right)-F\left(\frac{2j}{2^n}\right)\right]Z\left(\frac{2j-1}{2^n}\right)$$

where $\sigma_n = 2^{-(n+1)/2}$.  And it is suggested that the identity follows naturally from Levy's construction of Brownian Motion

$$B\left(\frac{2j-1}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[B\left(\frac{(2j-2)}{2^n}\right)+B\left(\frac{2j}{2^n}\right)\right]+\sigma_n Z\left(\frac{2j-1}{2^n}\right)$$ where $Z(t)$ are i.i.d standard normal R.V.s.

How can it be proved?